# How to setup a trap of storing in an address of memory in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, interrupt-handling

My C++ app should wait for storing value into some variable. And x86 has an ability to trap when storing in a range of addresses occurs. How can I implement it using Windows API? Use from C++ x86.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a thread to handle the write. Suspend the thread from another thread. In the other thread, get the registers from the first thread (`GetThreadContext`) and set the DR registers for that other thread. Then resume the other thread.